# JSON Stringify is making an object key with a value of array of objects empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Can someone help me with this, I am trying to achieve an object like so:

```
{ "docs": [
{ "_id": "item" },
{ "_id": "item" },
{ "_id": "item" }
] }
```

So I begin with having an object with a key docs which is an array I will push into

```
let query = { docs: [] };
```

i then have list of  key value pair items like so, around 80:

```
{ _id: item }
```

which i push into docs in a forEach loop

```
 query.docs.push(item);
```

So when I go and stringify

```
JSON.stringify(query);
```

it returns the object but the array is empty.

```
{ "docs": [] }
```

I’ve no idea why this is happening. Anyone know an approach to go around this to achieve the desired result? Thanks in advance

> Actual code:

```
let elasticQuery = {
    docs: []
  };

  axios({
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    url: sent2VecUrl,
    data: {
      selected_text: query
    }
  }).then(results => {
    results.data.response.forEach(item => {
      elasticQuery.docs.push({ _id: item });
    });
  });


  console.log("without: " + elasticQuery + " with stringify :" + JSON.stringify(elasticQuery));
```

> This is the server response:

[image]

Comment: This looks ok, can you show us the actual code though?

Comment: What's in the response?

Comment: The problem is that `JSON.stringify(elasticQuery)` is executed before `results.data.response.forEach......`, before you `push` values into the `elasticQuery.docs` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your console in .then function. This is asyn call and your console is printing before your promise is getting resolved.

```
axios({
method: "post",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
url: sent2VecUrl,
data: {
  selected_text: query
}})
.then(results => {
   results.data.response.forEach(item => {
      elasticQuery.docs.push({ _id: item });
   });
   console.log("without: " + elasticQuery + " with stringify :" + JSON.stringify(elasticQuery));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i moved the console.log to that position and it indeed showed changes, i completely missed the async aspect.

Comment: There was a guy who posted the answer but then deleted it before i could accept :( anyway i think it works now

Answer (score 0):

You code looks fine.

```
.then(results => {
    results.data.response.forEach(item => {
      elasticQuery.docs.push({ _id: item });
    });

      console.log(elasticQuery); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
results.data.response.forEach(item => {
      elasticQuery.docs.push({ _id: item });
});
```

do this:

```
  elasticQuery.docs = results.data.response.map(item => ({ _id: item }) )
```